# How to update Excel Sheet In SharePoint 2010 (Sharepoint Online)?

Tags: sandbox-solution, excel, office-365, openxml

I am working with SharePoint Online(Office 365).
I have some Excel files uploaded in a SharePoint library and I need to update one of the file data using c# code. My solution in Sandbox solution.

I already tried to update the file using the Open XML 2.0 framework (from the openXml 2.0 dll) but its not working properly.

Can anyone provide any guidance on the matter? Which would be the simpliest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use the restful excel services to update the document?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556413.aspx

It does seem like you need a certain plan for this to work though.

Comment: Thanks Steve Lineberry.. But my requirement is so different.. I have to open Excel File which is stored in shared document Library and update data in it.

Comment: Right, how does the excel services NOT do that?